# How can I disable Windows file locking on Samba shares?

Tags: windows, samba, microsoft-office-2007, clearos

When I open a Microsoft Office file from one of my Samba shares and then I disconnect and reconnect from the network I have to save my files as a copy because the file was somehow changed to read-only. I need to be able to save files/overwrite them even after leaving and reconnecting to the network.

ClearOS 5.2
Samba version 3.5.14-1.1.v5
Windows 7 64-bit & Windows XP Clients

Comment: After editing/saving a file, are the file permissions themselves changed? (i.e rwxrwxrwx to r-xr-xr-x)?  Or are the files locked/"not available for editing"?

Comment: I will check for that when I get back from vacation on the 13th.

Comment: The file permissions aren't being changed after editing/saving. However I did notice that the Office 2007 lock file is still around even after closing the program and saving the document. Here's what "ls -l" returned for it:

Comment: The permissions aren't being changed after editing/saving. However, I did notice that the Office 2007 lock file (file beginning with '~$') is still on my samba share even after saving and closing. Does this have anything to do with my issue and how do I fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure if its the default option but you could check to see if oplocking is enabled.

More information can be found [here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/locking.html)

Comment: Oplocking and all other locks have been disabled in the smb.conf and share definitions.

Comment: It seems that this is an issue exclusive to MS Office. :P